# sha256 based on different outcomes

Tags: sha256

Is it posible to know the `$server_seed` value based on the different outcomes of this code?

```
$server_seed = "**4799e37e2f397e6196813367a11042335521f8d2**"; (unknown value)

$round_id = 73904; (known value);

$round_date = "2016-01-23-11-59-37"; (known value)

$hash = hash("sha256", $server_seed . "-" . $round_id . "-" . $round_date);

$roll = bcmod(hexdec(substr($hash, 0, 8)), 15);

echo $roll;
```

The code gives a value betwen **0** and **14** every time that `$round_id` increases by 1 and `$round_date` is increased by 45 seconds. I have access to tons of different outcomes and I know their `$round_id` and `$round_date`, but `$server_seed` is unknown (is always the same lenght).

My question is if there is a way to know the `$server_seed` value using different outcomes, like making a code that checks the different `$server_seeds` values and tells you what values would give you the outcomes you inserted.

Is there anyway to get the `$server_seed` value in a easy and simple way?

Comment: There are several cryptographic functions that are well proven such as `HMAC`, `PBKDF2` and `crypt`. Using well vetted cryptographic functions is always preferable to writing your own. ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way. `Sha256` is a cryptographic hash function and completely satisfies the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) of such function:

> A cryptographic hash function is a hash function which is considered
>   practically impossible to invert.

Presently no successful attacks have been reported on [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)

As the other answer notes, only brute-force attack is possible that is unfeasible to perform at the current state of the existing computing technologies and hardware.

Answer (score 0):

No simple way. Dictionary or brute force.